# Question about moving Ubuntu partition guide step 6: grub-install -d

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I've been following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition and I have a question about step 6. It tells me to run `sudo grub-install -d /media/<new partition uuid>/usr/lib/grub/[instance] /dev/sda` "Where [instance] is the version you want to make bootable", but its vague what the "version I want to run" is...Sorry for the possibly dumb question. I tried to google this but couldnt come up with good keywords so I didn't find anything helpful.

All I see in that location now is `grub-mkconfig_lib  i386-pc/`, and when I try

`sudo grub-install -d /media/91a82071-fccd-4fdd-80e7-654acba2fe6e/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib /dev/sda`

I get

`grub-install: error: /media/sid/91a82071-fccd-4fdd-80e7-654acba2fe6e/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.`

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo grub-install -d /media/91a82071-fccd-4fdd-80e7-654acba2fe6e/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/ /dev/sda
```

I had a similar problem and it worked. That's because it's looking for a file within that directory called `modinfo.sh` (just like you wrote). You can look for that file in said directory.